# Is it possible to find out whether one given page has been indexed?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, search-engine-indexing

When one submits sitemaps in Google Webmaster, Google may not index all pages of your site/blog.

Is there a way to find out whether one specific page belonging to the sitemap has been indexed or not? If yes, how?

Of course, I could take a look at Traffic > Search Queries > Top Pages, but I would have no guarantee that my page is indexed or not if it does not appear there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for the indexing status of individual URLs is generally futile, especially when you have a website that's a bit larger than "10" pages (depending on how much time you have :)).

One thing that might make sense is to split the website into logical chunks, and to create Sitemap files using those chunks. For each Sitemap file, you can see how many URLs from there were indexed, so with that information, you could determine how well those chunks are indexed.

Comment: Temporary sitemap of one item, that's a good idea...

Comment: How many sitemaps are allowed ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a specific way to do this within GWT. However, you could do a `site:` search for that "one specific page".

Comment: an "info:URL" query also generally works.