# How to create and submit multiple sitemaps into categories?

Tags: sitemap, search-engine-indexing, xml

I have a questions. I need to know how to create and submit multiple sitemaps into categories? This is for a big online auction site with a lot of products that needs to be indexed.

Comment: Define "lots." If the total number of items is [below 50000](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183668&topic=8476&ctx=topic) there's no real point in you doing this.

Comment: @Su' [John Mueller suggested splitting the sitemap](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/42231/1243) if you wished to determine how well different parts of the site were being indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You do this this same as with a standard sitemap. Simple create the multiple sitemaps for the different areas and then you can submit them to Google. Even better would be to then collate them into another sitemap file which details the other sitemaps available. This is all well documented by Google here:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ie/2006/10/multiple-sitemaps-in-same-directory.html